# Import CSV to partitioned table on BigQuery using specific timestamp column?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to import a large csv to a bigquery partitioned table that has a timestamp type column that is actually the date of some transaction, the problem is that when I load the data it imports everything into one partition of today's date.

Is it possible to use my own timestamp value to partition it? How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery, currently, partitioning based on specific column is not supported.
Even if this column is date related (timestamp).
You either rely on time of insertion so BigQuery engine will insert into respective partition or you specify which exactly partition you want to insert your data into
See more about [Creating and Updating Date-Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that today is by using Google Dataflow [1]. You can develop a streaming `pipeline` which will read the file from Google Cloud Storage bucket and insert the rows into BigQuery's table.

You will need to create the partitioned table manually [2] before running the pipeline, because Dataflow right now doesn't support creating partitioned tables

There are multiple examples available at [3]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables

[3] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/all-examples